# A compiler's evaluation of the size of an array's declaration. When does it take place?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, compiler-construction, size

This is more for clarity or a better understanding of the internal workings of compilers: I'm beginning to study compiler design and compiler theory.

Typically When declaring the size of an array on the stack it has to be known at compile-time and this is understood, but this is not always the case.

What I would like to know is; when does this evaluation occur? Does it happen during the precompiler, tokenizer, syntax analysis, etc.? Also, does it depend on the particular compiler that is being used? Finally, is the point in time of this evaluation specified to be at any particular stage of a compiler within the language standards?

Pseudo Code snippet. C or C++

```
int main() {
    int x[5]; // When does the evaluation of the 5 for the array's size take place 
              // during the compilation process? 
              // Does it take place during pre-compiler or normal compilation time. 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why does it matter? Since `constexpr` functions can't have side effects, you can't determine when it's evaluated.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's not what I was getting at... I'll give a pseudo-code snippet.

Comment: I guess [C phase 8](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2) (have no idea about C++)

Comment: I asked this for clarity... It has to pertain more with the internal workings of a compiler and their design... and how they interpret or evaluate an array where it's size must be constant and known at compile time... Does this occur during the pre-processor stage or during normal compilation?

Comment: The preprocessor has nothing to do with array sizes. It doesn't even understand what an array is.

Comment: For C++ it appears to be [phase 7](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).

Comment: This might be not that helpful, but it is done at the syntax analysis (fronted) stage I believe. At least if you would use `clang -S -emit-llvm test.c` you would see the LLVM-IR which already has this information and which is not optimized yet and will be later lowered down to machine code. Also I think if you look around you might find compiler flags which enables you to dump the result of certain phases and that way you might could figure this out.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I wasn't sure if it was within the pre-compile stage or during tokenization or syntax analysis as Eraklon had mentioned. As I stated, it was only for clarity. It doesn't really have any importance or any direct relevance to any code design. Just a better understanding of the internal workings of compilers, compiler design and compiler theory!

Comment: Define (1) precompilation, (2) preprocessing, (3) first pass, (4) second pass, for a specific compiler, and then (5) tell us what difference it makes to you.

Comment: "When declaring arrays the size has to be known at compile-time.." C supports variable-length arrays, which means technically it needn't be known during compilation at all. The array dimension can be a variable 'a' instead of '5' and it would still work with any modern C compiler! C++ technically doesn't have VLAs but some C++ compilers support it as a non-standard extension anyway.

Comment: An implementation is not required to do "precompiler, tokenizer, syntax analysis" as a "canonical" implementation does. A theoretical implementation can, for example, scan, parse, and execute at the same time. In other words, the standard doesn't define "stages of a compiler"; the phases of translation are specified solely for the purpose of determining the semantics of the program. Therefore, this question is difficult to interpret from the standard's perspective, and the answer thereof differs among implementation models.

Comment: @th33lf That's not what I was getting at... you can not do this: "int x = 5; int y[x];" this will fail to compile because "x" is not constant! It has to be known. What I was getting at was the evaluation of its constant size...

Comment: @L.F. Thank you for the clarity on that. I was thinking on those lines but wasn't completely sure.

Comment: @FrancisCugler You can do exactly that. It works perfectly fine in C. https://godbolt.org/z/YQNUmn

Comment: @th33lf, I haven't worked with C in a long time so this may have changed over the years with recent compilers... but if you were trying to get the value of `x` from say, std::cin and store that into x and use x to declare the size of y, it would generate a compiler error that x isn't constant. Then again the languages and compilers are evolving over time too...

Comment: @FrancisCugler There is no `std::cin` in C, but there is definitely `scanf` and of course it still works even if `x` is not a constant! Why is this so difficult to understand? https://godbolt.org/z/jajK5n

Comment: @th33lf It's not difficult to understand, I just haven't used the C library in probably 10+ years... been mostly working in C++... I wasn't concerned about language specifics here, more about compiler implementations in general.

Comment: @FrancisCugler You question had both C and C++ tags, which is why I decided to point out the difference in behaviour between C & C++.

Comment: @th33lf Not a problem, I appreciate any and all feedback. Like, I've been saying, it's more about compiler design and internal intrinsics during their stages or pipelines. I just wanted clarity of when an array's size takes place. Or, which internal part of the compiler is responsible for determining the size at compile time.

Comment: Resolution of constant array sizes occurs during phase 7 of the 8 phases defined by the C standard in C 2018 5.1.1.2 1.

Answer (score 3):

The C standard specifies eight phases of translation:

1. Physical source multibyte characters and trigraph sequences are mapped to characters of the source character set.
2. Each backslash followed by a new-line is deleted (splicing together two lines).
3. The source characters are grouped into preprocessing tokens, and each sequence of white-space characters is replaced by one space, except new-lines are kept.
4. Preprocessing directives and _Pragma operators are executed, and macro invocations are expanded.
5. Source characters in strings and character constants are converted to the execution character set.
6. Adjacent string literals are concatenated.
7. Each preprocessing token is converted into a grammar token, and white-space characters separated tokens are discarded. The resulting tokens are analyzed and translated (compiled).
8. All external references are resolved (the program is linked).

Resolution of constant array dimensions thus occurs in phase 7. However, the phases are largely conceptual. The phases explain how the C language is understood, not how a compiler must execute.

For compilers that produce object modules, the sizes of arrays with static storage duration are necessarily resolved before the object information is written, as the array size affects data layout, which must be completely described in the object module. Handling of the sizes of arrays with automatic storage duration could theoretically be left until the program is actually executing code that needs them, as this is necessarily the case for variable length arrays. However, it would be wasteful to do so, since constant array sizes are easily handled during compilation, and it is preferably for the necessary values (such as the amount of stack space to reserve when entering a function) to be calculated at compilation time rather than during execution. So we can expect that normal compilers resolve all constant array sizes during compilation (that is, before completing an object module for the translation unit) and conceptually after phase 6.

Additional identification of points within the translation process where array sizes are resolved is dependent on internal details of the compiler implementation (or of a C implementation generally).

Answer (score 1):

After reading through the comments from various users it has come to my conclusion that there is nothing specific within the standard. There are differences between C and C++ on their implementation details of whether or not variable-sized arrays are permitted within the language within the stack frame.

When it comes to compiler design there is no context for the pre-processor. When it comes to stages of the compiler it depends on the language to which stage it belongs and it appears that it is also agnostic between compilers and their design. It appears that it is left up to the implementation design of the compiler for which stage this evaluation takes place.

Some C++ compilers may do this during syntax analysis while others may do this during tokenization. So in the end, the only true way to determine when this actually takes place is to know the particular compiler inside and out and to read through its own source code to see how it was designed and to step through the process of the compilation stages or phases.

Thank you everyone for your input and feedback. Please, by all means, correct me if I'm wrong by leaving a comment under this answer.